# how to connect to hive using golang

Tags: go, hive

I use https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/trunk/service/if/TCLIService.thrift to gen golang sdk, but it ddn't work. The golang sdk can only opensession. I compare my code within python sdk and didn't find any error usage. below is my golang code.

```
socket, err := thrift.NewTSocket("localhost:11000")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
    return
}
trans := thrift.NewTBufferedTransport(socket, 1024)

protocol := thrift.NewTBinaryProtocol(trans, true, true)
client := hive.NewTCLIServiceClientProtocol(trans, protocol, protocol)
trans.Open()
defer trans.Close()

sReq := hive.NewTOpenSessionReq()
sReq.ClientProtocol = 0

session, err := client.OpenSession(sReq)
fmt.Printf("!%#v %s\n", session, err)

exeReq := hive.NewTExecuteStatementReq()
exeReq.SessionHandle = session.SessionHandle
exeReq.Statement = "USE default"

result, err := client.ExecuteStatement(exeReq)
fmt.Printf("result: %s !! %s\n", result, err)
```

and the output is :

```
!&hive.TOpenSessionResp{Status:(*hive.TStatus)(0xc21001e460), ServerProtocolVersion:0, SessionHandle:(*hive.TSessionHandle)(0xc2100002b0), Configuration:map[string]string{}} %!s(<nil>)

result: <nil> !! Required field 'guid' is unset! Struct:THandleIdentifier(guid:null, secret:null)
```

Required field 'guid' is unset! Struct:THandleIdentifier(guid:null, secret:null) is return by the server. I have try other hive functions, always the same error.

Is there something wrong with my code or thirft didn't support golang yet?

Comment: Couple ideas:

1. It says the guid isn't set. Have you locked at the HandleIdentifier from the returned session?
2. Is `ClientProtocol = 0` correct? Maybe try HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V7.

Comment: Thanks. I found it's the thrift generated code. In THandleIdentifier i change WriteBinary to WriteString, and it work

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason. In the thrift generated file `ttypes.go`, the `THandleIdentifier` struct write guid and secret using binary protocol, and I found official Python SDK write guid and secrete use `WriteString` function of binary protocol, so I modify the code manual.

```
func (p *THandleIdentifier) writeField1(oprot thrift.TProtocol) (err error) {
if p.Guid != nil {

    // the origin code is:
    //if err := oprot.WriteFieldBegin("guid", thrift.BINARY, 1); err != nil {

    if err := oprot.WriteFieldBegin("guid", thrift.STRING, 1); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%T write field begin error 1:guid: %s", p, err)
    }

    //the origin code is:
    //if err := oprot.WriteString(p.Guid; err != nil {
    if err := oprot.WriteString(string(p.Guid); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%T.guid (1) field write error: %s", p)
    }
    if err := oprot.WriteFieldEnd(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%T write field end error 1:guid: %s", p, err)
    }
}
  return err
}
```

and the same with secret property need to modify.